# Can I use Drupal plugin in managing news?

Tags: theming, feeds, social-network

Can I use the plugin of Drupal twitter feed on managing news? Is there a twitter feed for Managing News? Sorry for this dumb question, as I was new on this content management system.

Comment: Hello. Of course you can, but we don't do "design whole site from set of requirements" here. If you have a problem with specific part of the process, please ask it :)

Comment: Thanks for that! :) One more question, is there a twitter feed for Drupal? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hello too, Maybe you should start by browsing [Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/) modules. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [Twitter Feed](https://drupal.org/project/tweet_feed)! with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) & [OAuth](https://drupal.org/project/oauth) modules and you have to enable OAuth based access for Twitter, you must register your application with Twitter and add the provided in Twitter setting!